# Eclipse leaving stuff behind that I can't kill

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 for Android development.

Every so often when I shut down Eclipse it puts up a dialog box with a progress bar called "saving workspace" that gets about 20% of the way across and just hangs there.  This is a known and reported bug in Eclipse, and it's **NOT** what this question is about.

On the web the usual solution when that happens is to go into Task Manager and kill Eclipse.exe.  I do that and I also kill adb.exe.   But the "saving workspace" progress bar remains, and it even shows up with the Eclipse icon on the task bar at the bottom of my screen.   I don't see anything in Task Manager that corresponds to this.   How do I get rid of it, short of rebooting my whole PC?

Comment: rather than killing eclipse.exe directly did you try ending the task or killing the entire process tree instead? That will clean up all related processes rather than just that one

Comment: Yes, I did kill the whole tree.   I should have been clearer about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `java` or `javaw` process shown in the Task Manager as well. You may want to make sure it corresponds to the Eclipse process. Try killing this as well (as usual you should anticipate weird things when you do this forcefully, e.g. I sometimes experience slight workspace changes when I re-launch Eclipse after killing `javaw`).

Also Indigo seems to be a relatively old version of Eclipse, which you may want to upgrade. Better yet, use Android Studio if you want to program with Android.

Comment: Thanks.  Javaw did it.   This is a huge industrial-control app with about 30 java files and about 20 xml layout files and over 100 other resource files and it's been around for years and I dread the effort of trying to port it over to Android Studio, but yes I agree that any new development should be done in Android Studio.